# dotnet ef database update not creating tables from existing migrations in EF Core and .NET 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to add tables via my existing migrations so I can work on this locally on another machine.

I'm running the `dotnet ef database update` command in the terminal, but it doesn't create any of the tables - it only gets as far as:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.7 initialized 'PingContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.7' with options: None
```

and that's the end of the command. It doesn't create the tables at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can run ```dotnet ef migrations script``` to see the generate script

Comment: did this, the script looks fine, just dont update the database!